# which characters must be escaped when running perl -e on the command line

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

I'm running perl -e on the command line to use perls regex functionality to find and replace a string across many files.  However, I've tested my regex in a script as well as many regex testers, but it doesn't seem to work on the command line.  So I've begun to wonder if because its the command line I'm needing to escape extra  characters.  For example, I know that I have to escape `$` when I'm using it as a variable, so I thought perhaps I'm needing that in my command.  I'm using linux.

heres my command:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/"flags" : {[^"]+"CP" : 1[^"]+"prop_name" : "ID"[^:]+: "SKU"/"flags" : {          "SET" : 1       },       "prop_name" : "ID",       "rule" : "SKU+ProductId"/gms;' *_input.xml
```

I'm trying to match parts of:

```
   {
      "flags" : {
         "CP" : 1
      },
      "prop_name" : "ID",
      "rule" : "SKU"
   },
```

so that the inside is changed to:

```
   {
      "flags" : {
         "SET" : 1
      },
      "prop_name" : "ID",
      "rule" : "SKU+ProductId"
   },
```

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work"*? Care to explain what doesn't work, any errors, what have you tried etc?

Comment: Any chance you could include an example of a match and how it is modified?

Comment: Is this windows or linux?

Comment: @grebneke I've tried the command I listed, its not replacing the text as I expect.  If i run the same regex in a stand alone perl script though it works.

Comment: @abiessu added match example to question

Comment: @AKHolland I'm using linux and perl 5.14

Comment: So you are trying to parse and alter JSON with regex in an XML file? Hmm. Sure that's the right approach to the problem? I guess there's more than one file or more than one structure you want to change.

Comment: @simbabque yeah, 600 similiar files, or I wouldn't even consider this :(

Comment: If it's the same regex every time, why don't you just put it in a file `foo.pl` and run that instead of `-e`?

Comment: @simbabque whats the syntax for using foo.pl

Comment: `perl -pi -w foo.pl *_input.xml` with the content being the same as inside the `-e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you? As you are doing a multiline match, but the perl one-liner matches one row at a time, the pattern will fail as soon as you hit newline in your input file.

```
perl -0777 -pi -w -e 's/"flags" : {[^"]+"CP" : 1[^"]+"prop_name" : "ID"[^:]+: "SKU"/"flags" : {          "SET" : 1       },       "prop_name" : "ID",       "rule" : "SKU+ProductId"/gms;' *_input.xml
```

Adding `-0777` makes perl use the whole file for input. See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-0%2a%5B_octal/hexadecimal_%5D) for more info.

Comment: You sir, are awesome.  Thanks for the answer and the reference!  I'm going to refer to you as the buddha because i am enlightened.